# java write data to file without erasing the old content

Tags: java

how can i
write data to file without erasing the old content

Comment: Start upvoting useful answers and marking as accepted those that solve your problem.

Comment: @Alberto Zaccagni: stop upvoting answers without also upvoting the question.   Tssst, I **know** you're doing it ;)

Comment: @SpoonBender: Uhm... yeah... sure... (ps: what? ^^")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `new FileOutputStream(file, true)`. This will open file in "append" mode which will append all data written to the stream to the end of that file.

Comment: what if I want to write data at begin or middle of file?

Answer (score 5):

You mean "how do you append to a file"?  Look for an [append-version of a constructor][1] of your File writing class, e.g.:

```
public FileWriter(String fileName,
                  boolean append)
           throws IOException
```

Use this constructor and pass `true` for the append parameter.

[1]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File, boolean)

Answer (score 0):

if you used the new one in Java 7, you can use this way

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the `BufferedWriter` add this string of code:

```
bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file),true);
```

Last `true` statement will give the command to not delete your data from the file.

Comment: According to docs the second argument of `BufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz)` is integer offset: "Output-buffer size, a positive integer". You've probably wanted to pass the boolean argument to `FileWriter`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Comment: `BufferedWriter` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: And `true` is not a statement.